# How to Cast Individual Fields Within Pig Map

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to load some data from HDFS via Pig and have one problem - I need to convert one of the fields in a Map from string to float. What's the easiest way to do this?

I tried defining the input schema on LOAD but found that I can only categorize everything in the map as a float, not the individual fields.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (f1:int, f2:map[float]);
```

The crux of the problem is that 2/3 fields in the map are true floats and the third field is a string so the string is being dropped in this method. Can anyone give me pointers on the best way to proceed with this problem?